# Select dropdown options disappears in IE 8

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have an issue with the select elements on my site in IE 8. Whenever the select is clicked, the options show but once you hover over the options to click it, the select menu disappears. I have been doing a lot of troubleshooting on this and I noticed that it doesnt behave this way when jquery is not added to the page. However, once I include the jQuery script, it starts behaving like that again.

I have been searching for a while now but can't seem to find the solution that works.
Ps: I have set position:relative;z-index:0; in the CSS.

```
<select>
<option value="1">ds</option>
<option value="2">df</option>
<option value="3">dr</option>
<option value="4">dw</option>
</select>
```

Comment: please share your code that you have tried so far.

Comment: it is basically any select element in a page with jquery.

Comment: There must be some other jquery plugin or code on the page which is causing this. HTML+jQuery with the CSS you mention alone wouldn't cause this.

Comment: Unless you show a piece of code that you tried, its really difficult to help you!

Comment: Found that it was because of selectivizr on the page. Apparently it does something to select elements with hover styles.